# Add value Y to value X each time a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I might be missing the elephant in the room here, but I can't figure this out.

What I want to do, add Y amount to variable X each time a button is clicked. Y is passed through the onClick function.

```
addStat: function(button, amount, price) {
    var curPrice = price;
    var priceHtml = $(button).closest("tr").find('.price');

    curPrice += price;

    $(priceHtml).text(curPrice);

},
```

This is what I have, but I have a feeling that I'd Need to set a value to current price, outside the function maybe? I tried but then It'd always reset on each button press.

Any idea/suggestion is welcome. I'm kinda of new to JS. Just learning.

One method I know would work, if I'd get the value of the price HTML element. But the issue with that, is that it can be edited with chrome inspect.

Comment: This statement `var curPrice = price;` need to be outside the function, and like this `var curPrice = 0;` If the passed `price` is not a number, you need to convert it, e.g. `curPrice += Number(price)`

Comment: Hmm, how would I use the `price` variable outside tho? if it comes in when the button is pressed. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Not the `price` variable, the `curPrice` variable, or else it gets reset on every click

Comment: Oh, but the initial value has to be equal to the price. and on click, increase it by the prices value. Due to each item having a different price, that's passed through when the button is clicked.

Comment: But that happens on the first click either way, as you won't have an initial value until its been clicked in the first place, or else there is some code missing here.

Comment: The initial price is added when the person selects the item from a list, that has prices / amount values. But maybe it'd be easier to set those values to 0 so both price and value is 0 at the start?

Comment: Well, I can only help with what I see, and the code provided, so I can't say what would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the current price value using `priceHtml.text()` and assign it to your `curPrice` variable.

Try this:

```
var priceHtml = $(button).closest("tr").find('.price');
var curPrice = parseFloat(priceHtml.text())||0;

curPrice += price;

priceHtml.text(curPrice);
```

Comment: This works, but there's one issue, it can be manipulated through the browser's inspect function.

Comment: `$(priceHtml)` appears to be completely redunant, you can just use `priceHtml` And you should describe what you are doing and why. 
@AndorNagy Anything we do can be manipulated through the browsers inspect function or console.

Comment: @AndorNagy everything can be manipulated using the inspector, even global variables.

Comment: So basically there's no way around it? I should just go with getting the value from the html element and go from there?

Comment: If you want something hidden, it shouldn't be on your frontend

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your `let curPrice = 0;` outside the function, on top of your code. Then you can simply use `curPrice += parseFloat(price);` inside the function. That prevent the wrong overwriting value of curPrice.

EDIT -> Example:

```js
let curPrice = 0;

function updatePrice(button, amount, price) {
    if(!isNaN(price)) {
      curPrice += price;
      return $(button).find('.price').text(curPrice.toFixed(2));
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="updatePrice(this, 10.00, 10.00)">
  <span class="price">0.00</span>
</button>

<button onclick="updatePrice(this, 10.00, 'isNaN')">
  <span class="price">Not working!</span>
</button>
```

And use `let variable;` instead of `var variable;`

Another example:

```js
function updatePrice(button, amount, price) {
  //Find the .price inside the clicked button
  let $price = $(button).find('.price');
  //Test if price is numeric
  if(!isNaN(price)) {
    //If is numeric retrive the current price and add the price
    let newPrice = parseFloat($price.text()) + parseFloat(price);
    //Return the new price and print it on .price inside the button
    return $price.text(newPrice.toFixed(2)); // .toFixed(2) return 2 decimal.
  }
  //If price is not numeric return false
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- price is numeric so it works -->
<button onclick="updatePrice(this, 10.00, 10.00)">
  <span class="price">10.00</span>
</button>
<!-- price is not numeric so the function return false -->
<button onclick="updatePrice(this, 10.00, 'not numeric')">
  <span class="price">10.00 (not working)</span>
</button>
```

Good luck!

Comment: i would avoid doing this and creating global variables. that's going to be a much bigger headache later on.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reduce what you're trying to do to just a minimum example. From your question, it sounds like you're trying to do four things on a click:

- take in the text value of an element
- coerce that value to a number
- double the number
- write the new value to the element

You don't have to move the `curPrice` var outside of the function. It doesn't matter that you redeclare it on each click, because you're immediately doubling it against itself. And you'll want to parse the incoming text to a number with [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), otherwise javascript will assume you're trying to do string concatenation:

```js
function addStat(event) {
    var curPrice = parseInt(event.target.textContent, 10);

    curPrice += curPrice;

    $(event.target).text(curPrice);
}

$('.price').click(addStat)
```

```css
.price {
  background-color: #ace;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="price">1</div>
<div class="price">3</div>
```